# How to compile this project (makefile, .rc, .p) in Windows?

Tags: compile, ide, open-source, source-code

How do I compile the [z-wamp project](http://sourceforge.net/p/zwamp/code/ci/default/tree/) in Windows?

```
 makefile   2012-03-20  bcosca bcosca   [6a5635] 2.1.1 pre-release
 manifest.rc    2012-03-15  bcosca bcosca   [99a236] 2.1.0 baseline
 zwamp.ico  2012-03-15  bcosca bcosca   [99a236] 2.1.0 baseline
 zwamp.manifest 2012-03-15  bcosca bcosca   [99a236] 2.1.0 baseline
 zwamp.p    2012-03-20  bcosca bcosca   [6a5635] 2.1.1 pre-release
 zwamp.rc   2012-03-20  bcosca bcosca   [6a5635] 2.1.1 pre-release
```

I can't easily look at the source and understand the code but i really don't know how to recompile it and build an .exe. Minor modifications needed.

Which IDE do I need?

Comment: I have taken a look at the source code of the linked project. The code is written in *Delphi* (also known as Turbo Pascal). I don't know which version of Delphi, though. I can't find any usage of "new" features, so I think it's enough to compile it with Borland's old Delphi 7 (I don't have a link to the installer but the developer released free keys: http://www.entwickler-ecke.de/topic_Offiziell+freigegebene+Delphi+7+Personal+Seriennummer_92913,0.html text inside white rectangle)

Comment: @GiantTree Cannot find Delphi 7. Is possible to use Lazarus instead? If yes, do you know how?

Comment: Looking at the wiki about Lazarus, I think it's simple to use Lazarus for that task. Just create a new project, add all the code and resources to the project and compile it. I can't find a reason for it to not work.